# initializing tensor of zeors and ones

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor that gives the row indices of rows that I would like to be initialized to ones. It looks something like this:

```
[0 1 5 9]
```

For all other rows, I would like these to be initialized to zero. That is, I would like to initialize a rank 2 tensor where the rows 0, 1, 5, 9 are ones, whilst the rest are zeros.

I have looked at the initialize functions such as ones, zeros, and fill, but I am not having much luck creating a tensor of this specification.

I realise that I could evaluate this tensor to have it returned as a numpy array, and the use numpy to create a matrix of this form, but this does not fit within the structure of my code. I have tried to make it so I can do this, but I would have to remove placeholders and instead use numpy arrays within my tensorflow graph, which is not good practice.

Is there a function, or particular way where I would be able to creatr a tensor as above?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to assign values to a tensor (`t`) based on the values within another tensor (`t_0159`) i believe the correct method would be to evaluate `t_0159` within the session, and use the values returned to call a `tf.assign` operation to overwrite the content of `t` with values passed to a placeholder. Im not sure if this is what you described above, but it should not require any `numpy` arrays **within** the graph, just during the session.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# create placeholder for raplacement variables
values = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [10,10], name="values")

# sample tensors, one containing row indeces, other is arbitrary Variable
t_0159 = tf.constant([0,1,5,9])
t = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,10]), name = "my_tensor")

# define assignment operation to overwrite tensor t
assignment_op = tf.assign(t, values, name = "assignment_op")


# run session and call assignment_op
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # initialize variables and print tensor state
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("my_tensor:0").eval())

    # get indeces
    r_indeces = sess.run(t_0159)

    # create replacement tensor in numpy
    assignment_value = np.zeros([10,10])
    for i in r_indeces:
        assignment_value[i,:]= 1

    # run assignment op and printe new tensor state
    sess.run(assignment_op, feed_dict = {"values:0": assignment_value})
    print(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("my_tensor:0").eval())
```

I believe this is the "proper" way to do it, and produces an output:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

I hope this helps, if not let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way (maybe not the best) to do it.
Say that you want to create a tensor, with shape `(10, n_cols)`, with the constraint that the rows with indices in `rows=[0, 1, 5, 9]` are initialized to ones and the other ones are initialized to zeros.

```
import tensorflow as tf

rows = [0, 1, 5, 9]
n_cols = 10  # for the sake of the example...
my_tensor = [tf.get_variable(name='my_tensor_row_' + str(idx), 
                             shape=(1, n_cols),
                             initializer=tf.initializers.ones if idx in rows else tf.initalizers.zeros) 
             for idx in range(10)]
my_tensor = tf.concat(my_tensor, axis=0)
```

Then, you can access the value of `my_tensor` in a tensorflow Session:

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) # initialize the rows of `my_tensor`
my_tensor_val = sess.run(my_tensor)
```

will give you a Numpy array `my_tensor_val` with shape `(10, n_cols)` which is initialized as you wanted.